# Всплывающее сообщение после успешного действия asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, веб-программирование, вёрстка, asp.net-mvc

Пишу на asp.net mvc.
Я создал модальное окно с inputами на ajax+jquery.Все серверные проблемы решены, осталось только наладить визуал на клиенте. Хотелось бы доработать задумку и сделать так, чтобы после успешной отправки в бд выводилось всплывающее окно (на пару секунд и исчезало) на подобие такого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все алерты что я знаю - статичные(алерты бутстрапа, стандартный js алерт) и будут висеть пока на них не нажмешь или не обновишь страницу.

Есть у кого шаблоны таких вот всплывающих сообщений, которые показывают об успехе операции и затем исчезают без перезагрузки страницы

Comment: есть [Alertify.js](https://alertifyjs.org/#success-callback)

Comment: То что нужно, спасибо